# Unable to import movie

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm very new to using blender, I installed version 2.69 from the software center (using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).
Whenever I try to import a video into the sequencer I get the following error:

> File `File_name` could not be loaded

If I try to run blender from the terminal I get this error directly when I launch it:

> using fallback mode for management connect failed: No such file or directory

I don't understand what the error means or how to fix it, Any suggestions?

Comment: Try a different version, and try re-installing.

Comment: What format is the video in question? For a list of supported formats read **http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Formats**

Comment: @cegaton it is mp4

Comment: @user11463 Have you installed multiple versions like here:http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2169485.html

Comment: @stacker no I only installed it from the software center.

Comment: @user11463 could you run it from a terminal and append the exact error messages to your post.

Comment: @stacker it works now, I uninstalled blender 2.69 and downloaded the latest version from the official website. Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: @user11463 Is it ok for you when we then close the question because it is probably not helpful for other users.

Comment: @stacker yes how can I do that?

Comment: You need more reputation points to be able to vote to close a question. Don't worry about it.